# Set the width of a nested HTML element that is part of an Angular Directive to the same width of a parent element?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am making use of ng2-date-picker as a date component in my Angular app, but I am struggling to set the width of the component to be dynamic. I am using Bootstrap 4 columns for a responsive layout.

How can I set the width of a nested HTML element, that is part of an Angular Directive, targeted by `::ng-deep` in my SCSS, to the same width of a parent element (controlled by Bootstrap 4 styling)? Can this be done using SCSS?

`date-picker` is my parent element, and `dp-date-picker` is the Angular directive. Below is my code:

**SCSS**

```
.date-picker {
  font-family: $af-default-font;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 35px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: solid 1px $af-brownish-grey;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: $af-brownish-grey;
  ::ng-deep {
    input {
      &:last-child {
        border: none;
        font-family: $af-default-font;
        font-size: 18px;
        height: 33px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        background-image: url("/assets/icons/calendar (3).png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right 0px center;
        background-size: 20px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div
  [ngClass]="{
    'invalid-date': invalidDOB,
    'valid-date': validDOB,
    'date-picker': true
  }"
>
  <dp-date-picker
    #dayPicker
    id="dateOfBirth"
    placeholder="1999-12-31"
    theme="dp-material"
    name="dateOfBirth"
    ngModel
    mode="daytime"
    [config]="dateConfig"
    (ngModelChange)="dateOfBirthChange($event)"
    [(ngModel)]="model.dateOfBirth"
  >
  </dp-date-picker>
</div>
```

Comment: From the docs, `theme` is a class added to the datepicker. I think, that would be your entry point. Might be as simple as passing in a second class with `width: 100%`.

Comment: for the element you want to fix, add a class named grid, then in css create a grid class of :  diplay:grid; width:100%